# Is this problem of selecting points NP-hard?

Tags: optimization, np-complete, discrete-optimization

I have an optimization problem related, in a certain way, to the expression of a set of points with the least number of points and I don't know if it is NP-hard (or not).

More formally, I have a ground set $U$ of points with coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,...,n$.
Given an integer $k\leq n$, the decision problem consists in finding a subset $I$ (made of $k$ points) of $U$ such that every point of $U$ can be written as the convex combination of **at most two points of $I$**.

For example, let $U=\{(0,0) ; (1,3) ;(2,6); (3,0);(2,3/2);(4,3);(6,0)\}$.
There is a solution with $k=4$ wich is $I=\{(0,0) ; (2,6); (4,3);(6,0)\}$.
Indeed, we have $(1,3)=\frac{(0,0)+(2,6)}{2}$; $(2,3/2)=\frac{(0,0)+(4,3)}{2}$ and $(3,0)=\frac{(0,0)+(6,0)}{2}$.

I started looking into Garey & Johnson for some similarities with existing problems, but I don't see how to "express" the condition of the convex combination.

Thanks for any advice! (related problems, ...)

EDIT - IP formulation (but still no hardness result)

Let $C_{ij}$ be the indices of the points belonging to $U$ which can be expressed as a convex combination of $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j)$.
I think all these $C_{ij}$'s can be computed in $O(n^2)$ time.
Then we can write the following IP with $O(n^2)$ binary variables:
$$
\min x_1+...+x_n
$$
$$\sum_{(i,j)|p\in C_{ij}}y_{ij}\geq 1 \text{ for all } p=1,...,n,$$
$$y_{ij}\leq x_i, y_{ij}\leq x_j \text{ for all } i,j=1,...,n,$$
$$x_i\in\{0,1\} \text{ and } y_{ij}\in\{0,1\} \text{ for all } i,j=1,...,n.$$

Comment: You may get some "answers" offering an algorithm for finding $I$ but the ones that I can think of  take about $2^n$ steps.....  Also, although it can be found   in $O(n^3)$ steps whether each $p\in U$ is a convex linear combo of at most $2$  members of a given $J\subset U$, the problem of checking that $|J|$ is minimal is another matter..... I dk.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How do you do that in $O(n^3)$ steps? Thanks!

Comment: For $a\in U$ \ $J$ and $(b,c)\in J^2$ with $b\ne c$  the linear equation $rb+(1-r)c=a$  either has a unique  solution $r$ (that  may fail to belong to the interval $(0,1),$ or it has no solution.  For each $a\in U$ \ $J$ we need to check this for $\binom  {|J|}{2}$ pairs $(b,c),$ and there are |$U|-|J| $ different "$a$" to check. And $(|U|-|J|)\cdot \binom {|J|}{2}\leq n\binom {n}{2}.$